# SQLite for WinRT multiple primary keys?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

Is there a way to use annotate a composite key in SQLite for c#? The following code throws an exception saying the table has more than one primary key:

```
userDatabase.CreateTable<MyObject>();

//class file
[SQLite.Table("MyObject")]
public class MyObject
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int IdOne { get; set; }

    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int IdTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What exactly has anything to do with Entity Framework here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the current codebase, but there are several pull requests to get it fixed https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/pull/281

Comment: Thanks hopefully they can put out a fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. This is not the best solution, but it worked for me.

The idea is to make the composite key manually.
So, in your case, declare it:

```
userDatabase.CreateTable<MyObject>();

//class file
[SQLite.Table("MyObject")]
public class MyObject
{
    public int IdOne { get; set; }
    public int IdTwo { get; set; }

    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public string auxCompositeKey {get; set;}
}
```

Then, when you create the object, just make de auxCompositeKey as follows:

oMyObject.auxCompositeKey = IdOne.ToString()+IdTwo.ToString().

Comment: And what, if there will be two records, with
IdOne=1, IdTwo=23
and:
IdOne=12, IdTwo=3
;)?

Comment: It gonna blow! lol. It gonna need some update to work properly.. but the idea is that.